# Layout: How to put a list below a card view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

I have this layout (picture below). This CardView shows the information of a member. I have a list in the Room database. I want to let this layout show the list below the CardView. How can I do that?

This card here with a,b and c shows the member. Below that, I want the list shown.

[image: My layout]

Comment: which type of output you can get u have any screenshot ??

Comment: @MohammadAli how do you mean that? You mean if I try to implement the list?

Comment: no no my mean u have any other image like u want to a design

Comment: In the picture you see a card, right? I just want more cards below that card, but those cards are part of the list layout

Comment: see my below answer and also follow given link for batter understanding :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st add to library in your `gradle`:

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.+'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.+'
```

You can create a one activity and in activity take one `recyclerview`.

After that you can create a `Row` of `recyclerview` and in this row take a `cardview` and in this card view take `widgets`.

Create a model class and set `gatter` & `setter` method.

Create a Adapter class to set a row and bind the List.

No in activity initialize a `reyclerview` and set a adapter also set some static value in list.

Follow This link for perfect example : https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/

Comment: Your link gave me a hint to how I also could solve the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use a LinearLayout that holds a card and then the list below that:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- Your Current Card Layout Here -->
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        ...

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <!-- Your list of more cards -->
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" /

</LinearLayout>
```

Use a viewholder which uses the card view as its layout with the adapter

Answer (score 0):

take a linear layout and set it orientation to vertical and after that put your card view inside this linear layout first and then put your list view or recycler view.
result will be like card view will be shown first and the list view will be shown below the card view.